# Setting enable-gamepad-extensions from Chrome command line

Tags: google-chrome, gamepad, webvr

I cannot set `--enable-gamepad-extensions` from the Chrome command line
(WebVR experimental build Version 56.0.2902.0 (64-bit))

Setting `--enable-webvr` on the command line works fine, 
and setting `enable-gamepad-extensions` from `chrome://flags` also works fine.

I'm guessing it may be because `enable-gamepad-extensions` is a three way setting (default/enabled/disabled) rather than just a two way one.
I see that the corresponding entries in the Local State file is

```
"enabled_labs_experiments":["enable-gamepad-extensions@1","enable-webvr"]
```

and have tried various experiments based on this, but haven't found a way that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag was [added](https://crrev.com/2301463002) in [about_flags.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/browser/about_flags.cc?q="enable-gamepad-extensions"&dr=C&l=2028), not in command line [chrome_switches.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc). It was also added in [content_features.cc](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/public/common/content_features.cc?q=gamepad&l=77&dr=CSs) as 2-state (enabled/disabled) so you can force it with `--enable-features`:

```
chrome.exe --enable-features=GamepadExtensions
```

Comment: Many thanks.  Slight correction, I found I needed  
  
`chrome.exe --enable-features=GamepadExtensions`